# polar cordinates, finding teta

Tags: calculus, polar-coordinates

[the integral,and a picture of the graph of D](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LRCpk.jpg)

in the left corner you have the integral and below it the range D.
the right side has the ranges i found.

Hi im having a hard time understanding something i saw another student do.

the question was solving a double integral in a certain range of D.
i needed to  use polar cordinates to do so.

i found that the range of teta is (pi/4)<= teta <=(pi/3).
the person that solved this integral used  0  <=tetta<=  (pi/12)

i know the answer is the same, but in other excerises it might not be.
what am i doing wrong, or his he mistaken(he got a perfect score).

i dont need you to solve it, just explain if what i did was wrong, and why, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your setup is right. I was not able to find the calculation of the integral in the picture.

Since the angle between $\pi/4$ and $\pi/3$ is $\pi/12$, by symmetry your friend's setup is also right, and the calculation becomes (marginally) simpler.

If the integrand involved both $r$ and $\theta$, your setup would still be right, but because of the breakdown of angular symmetry, the other approach would not be right.

Comment: thank you so much, i was sure that i was missing something

Comment: @roi: You were missing essentially nothing, only the very small simplification allowed in this case because of the angular symmetry.